# Pulling data and displaying it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I am working in `react` and try to build a page for this web app that displays data.
I haven't even been able to get it to display the data for this page yet.

The code that I need to pull is from a web link, I need to pull that and display it on a card with material UI.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const STYLES = {
    card: {
      minWidth: 275,
    },
    //bullet: {
      //display: 'inline-block',
      //margin: '0 2px',
      //transform: 'scale(0.8)',
    //},
    //title: {
      //marginBottom: 16,
      //fontSize: 14,
    //},
    //pos: {
     // marginBottom: 12,
    //},
  };

class ErrorView extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.extractErrorData = this.extractErrorData.bind(this)
    }
    extractErrorData(errorDatas) {
        return errorDatas.map((errorViewData) => {
            <Card>
                <CardContent>
                    {'errorData.project'}
                </CardContent>
                <CardContent>
                    {'errorData.errorText'}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>

        })
    }

     render() {
        const { header, errorViewData } = this.props;
        return (
            <Paper elevation={4} Color='#fff'>
                <Typography variant="headline" component="h3">
                    {header}
                </Typography>
                {this.extractErrorData(errorViewData)}
            </Paper>
         );
    }
}
ErrorView = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

 export default withStyles(STYLES)(ErrorView);
```

Comment: Please check out: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes in extractErrorData if you want to show errorData.project and errorData.errorText values (and rename errorData with errorViewData):

```
extractErrorData(errorDatas) {
    return errorDatas.map((errorViewData) => {
        <Card>
            <CardContent>
                {errorViewData.project}
            </CardContent>
            <CardContent>
                {errorViewData.errorText}
            </CardContent>
        </Card>

    })
}
```

Note: you should add a JSFiddle or write something more to let us better understand what the problem is.